# How to show the new style notifications?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

Installed Ubuntu on my friends laptop. Notifications are showing in the old style, the stock gnome support. notify-osd is installed.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean "old style"? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.

I removed the `notification-daemon` package and the notify-osd started to show up.

version was 10.10